# post to SQL Server api with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express

I´ve been testing Apis with Express.js from SQL Server database. With get i have no problems, but i cannot post.

This is y code so far:

```
    const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
});

const dbConfig = {
    user: "daUser",
    password: "daPass",
    server: "daServer",
    database: "DaDB"
}

const executeQuery = function (res, query) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request();
            // query to the database
            request.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else {
                    res.send(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

app.get("/api/HolidayBaseApi", function (req, res) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM [HolidaysBase]";
    executeQuery(res, query);
})

app.post("/api/HolidayBaseApi", function (req, res) {
    var query = "INSERT INTO [HolidaysBase] (EmployeeNumber, PeriodBegin, PeriodEnd, WorkedYears, DaysPerYear, TakenDays, RemainingDays) VALUES (req.body.EmployeeNumber, req.body.PeriodBegin, req.body.PeriodEnd, req.body.WorkedYears, req.body.DaysPerYear, req.body.TakenDays, req.body.RemainingDays)";
    executeQuery(res, query);
})
```

When i'm triying to make the post, i get an error which says:

```
The multi-part identifier \"req.body.RemainingDays\" could not be bound.
```

The error list all my fields with the same error. The format of every field it's fine. I'm sending the data like this in postman:

```
{
    "EmployeeNumber": "9",
    "PeriodBegin": "2018-10-15",
    "PeriodEnd": "2019-10-15",
    "WorkedYears": "6",
    "DaysPerYear": "18",
    "TakenDays": "0",
    "RemainingDays": "18"
}
```

Someone knows why is not letting me post the info?

I'm using Javascript, Express.js, Node.

**--- EDITION ---**

I've found two solutions. The first solution next:

```
    app.post("/api/HolidayBaseApi", function (req, res) {        
    var query = "INSERT INTO [HolidaysBase] (EmployeeNumber, PeriodBegin, PeriodEnd, WorkedYears, DaysPerYear, TakenDays, RemainingDays) VALUES ('"+req.body.EmployeeNumber+"','"+req.body.PeriodBegin+"','"+req.body.PeriodEnd+"','"+req.body.WorkedYears+"','"+req.body.DaysPerYear+"','"+req.body.TakenDays+"','"+req.body.RemainingDays+"')";
    executeQuery(res, query);
});
```

With my code like this, i could make the post. But there was some comments that this way it's a little dangerous, 'cause it's easier to get an SQL attack injection. And found another solution: On the `const executeQuery` need to add `parameters` like this:

```
const executeQuery = function (res, query, parameters) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request();
            // query to the database

            parameters.forEach(function (p) {
                request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
            });

            request.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error al correr query en la base: " + err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else {
                    res.send(result);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Then, on the `app.post`:

```
app.post("/api/HolidayBaseApi", function (req, res) {
    var parameters = [
        { name: 'EmployeeNumber', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.EmployeeNumber },
        { name: 'PeriodBegin', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: req.body.PeriodBegin },
        { name: 'PeriodEnd', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: req.body.PeriodEnd },
        { name: 'WorkedYears', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.WorkedYears },
        { name: 'DaysPerYear', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.DaysPerYear },
        { name: 'TakenDays', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.TakenDays },
        { name: 'RemainingDays', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.RemainingDays },
    ];
    var query = "INSERT INTO [HolidaysBase] (EmployeeNumber, PeriodBegin, PeriodEnd, WorkedYears, DaysPerYear, TakenDays, RemainingDays) VALUES (@EmployeeNumber, @PeriodBegin, @PeriodEnd, @WorkedYears, @DaysPerYear, @TakenDays, @RemainingDays)";
    executeQuery(res, query, parameters);
});
```

It works this way too

Comment: can you log the "req.body" and see what you are getting? Also you have put req.body in string  format, you should make your query using req.body object values

Comment: on the console.log shows the data i'm sending. I've change the values putting like `VALUES ({req.body.EmployeeNumber, req.body.PeriodBegin, req.body.PeriodEnd, req.body.WorkedYears, req.body.DaysPerYear, req.body.TakenDays, req.body.RemainingDays})` and now i'm getting the next error: `Incorrect syntax near '.'."`

Comment: can you show me your full code and error log.I guess You have to concat all the values of body object as string. something like(req.body.EmployeeNumber+','+req.body.PeriodBegin) to make a perfect query

Comment: Sure, i'm going to edit my question. I've found a solution but i wanna know your opinion :)

Comment: Second solution is far better than first one . As you are joining string unsafely it could lead to SQL Injection attack.Imagine if  some one put "where 1=1 ' " in one of the parameter. From 'mssql' Package documentation in npm you will get more idea. You can also search for SQL Injection.